# SSMS Flat File Import (CSV): Data in wrong columns

Tags: sql, csv

I am having issues when importing data into a data table through the SQL Server Management Studio flat file import task. I am finding that data is being imported into the wrong column.

Example

```
CSV
A   | B
123   456

SQL
A   | B
      123 , 456
```

There doesn't seem to be a real reason for this (that I can determine). There are some rows with comas in them, but they are still valid (encompassed in quotes)

**Is this just an issue with the data importer? Is there a workaround if I am having trouble with the data?** I am going to try other formats, but I wanted to try and find another route, as I am worried about losing data.

**EDIT**
I noticed that most rows contained, or were before or after rows with commas in the data:

```
CSV: 
123,456,"text,text",543,654 

SQL: 
|123|456|"text|text"|543,654
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any issues in the affected lines, or maybe at the end of the previous line? Any strange character, maybe non-visible... Try saving your source file to ANSI charset to get rid of any possible issue, you could do this using plain Notepad.

Comment: I think it is an issue with commas, mixed with what you are saying. Rows look like this in csv: 123,456,"text,text",543,654 
and in sql:

|123|456|"text|text"|543,654

Comment: I can't remember the SMSS import procedure, but in Excel you should be able to import it correctly by setting fields comma separated, with " as text identifier. Then, you can export it as CSV again, maybe tabulated (or another separator than comma)

Comment: Or better, you could directly import your xls file into SMSS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import csv file into excel,save as excel format then import the excel file. It is more reliable this way.